# Can I submit my paper without author list (double-blind) to a conference with a single-blind review process?

Tags: peer-review, conference, paper-submission, anonymity

I am submitting a paper to a computer science conference, can I submit it without author list? The submission guideline says: "submissions are reviewed following a single blind review process, meaning, you do not need to hide authors’ names and affiliations"

The names, affiliations and conflicts of interests will be mentioned when I am submitting the paper. But can I remove name and affiliations from the paper (pdf)? Does it mean that the reviewer will not see it?

Secondly, is there any point in hiding these information, or they will find it out anyway?

Comment: My suggestion would be contacting one of the organizers directly and asking about it. It is possible that they accept to treat your submission as a double-blind one.

Answer (score 8):

In a single blind review process, the author names are not hidden for the reviewers, but the reviewer names are hidden for the authors.

In a double blind review process, the author names are hidden for the reviewers, and the reviewer names are hidden for the authors.

In both cases you will have to submit the author names during the submission process (e.g., in a web form), and the organizing committee will be able to see your names. Typically, for a conference or journal with a double blind review process, you are asked to provide a manuscript without any author names and affiliations.

You cannot submit an anonymous manuscript to a conference/journal with a single blind review process, as it probably will be rejected straight away.

Answer (score 5):

When I've been on the program committees of computer science conferences, the names of authors were always available even apart from the pdf files of the submissions.  But other conferences might work differently, so you should probably check with the chair of the program committee.

Comment: Is it the case for double-blind conferences as well?

Comment: @emab No, that would clearly defeat the entire purpose of making the review double blind.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Though "Blind to the Reviewers" = / = "Blind to the Committee"

Comment: @Fomite In the conferences I referred to, the program committee members served as reviewers (though they could farm the task out to sub-reviewers).

Answer (score 2):

In general, single-blind is single-blind.  Full stop.  Of course, you may try to negotiate with the PC chair, but the outcome is not guaranteed.  A busy PC chair might disregard such a request simply because he/she would have no time for special regulations.

What you can also try to negotiate (or simply do without asking anyone) is to submit under a pseudonym.  It is unusual, so I would not recommend it unless you do it right from the start and stick to that pseudonym for a long period of time.  If you go for a pseudonym, you should ponder about how you would handle spending part of your life under another name, about citation counts, etc. In short, you should be knowing what you are doing.